# Mysql NDB Cluster add another data node after setup

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing, nodes

I have a NDB Cluster setup with two data nodes, I want to add third data node in this. 
What steps do I need to follow?
For example :-
I have to install mysql server on that third server and change the config file add the third server ip.

Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-online-add-node-example.html) is a detailed example that should help, and [a more basic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-online-add-node-basics.html) one too